# memory allocation-deallocation in Debug mode (C ++ Builder)

Tags: debugging, c++builder

Salutations.
In general, calls to **new** keywords should be properly encoded with corresponding cleanup calls, such as **delete** (for example).
**Question: ALSO IN Debug mode is it mandatory to place calls to corresponding new / delete? (or the IDE takes care of everything)**

Thank you in advance,
Michele.

Comment: Use of `new`/`delete` is not dependent on whether you are compiling for Release or Debug.  You need to manage memory correctly regardless of the build type.

Comment: My question arose from a consideration:
- I launch the application with Debug,
- I create object with new,
- let's say the executable goes into block / endless loop / in any case I stop it,
- I have no solution but to abort the execution (CTRL+F2).

This being the case, the object would not be deleted.
I was hoping the IDE (in Debub mode) would care to do the cleanup automatically.
--NO--
Thanks again for the answer.
Greetings,
Michele Di Savino.

Comment: When you abort the exe stops running and then operating system (Windows typically) takes care of clean up (ie all of the memory used by the exe that is now not running is returned back to the operating system.

Comment: @disavmic IIRC Ctrl+F2 will kill a process .... usually OS will take care of it once the process is killed the OS will free its stuff  (memory and handles) however some stuff might still be hanging around (like separate threads especially those that are driver dependent) however I am afraid any other stuff might not be freed automatically (like streams, contexts etc ...)